# How to lead a link click to common page & activate tab items under React Router

Tags: reactjs, router

How to load corresponding SUB items and show as active for each 'Foundation Sub' link ? means

- click of Foundation Sub 1 should activate SUB 1 tab & its content
- click of Foundation Sub 2 should activate SUB 2 tab & its content
- click of Foundation Sub 3 should activate SUB 3 tab & its content
  Please help

  <Route path="FoundationSubAll" element={}

https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-router-ui-cvdzpe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use navigation `slugs` and `useParams` function in FoundationSubAll component.
I forked your codesendbox where you can find my solution.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-router-ui-forked-izyf2o?file=/src/FoundationSubAll.js

Answer (score 0):

List the subroutes of Foundation inside the Foundation route:

```
<Route path="Foundation" element={<Foundation />}>
  <Route path="FoundationSubA" element={<FoundationSubA />} />
  <Route path="FoundationSubAll" element={<FoundationSubAll />} />
  <Route path="FoundationSubB" element={<FoundationSubB />} />
  <Route path="FoundationSubC" element={<FoundationSubC />} />
</Route>
```

Then, in the Foundation component, link to the subroutes and add an Outlet:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
function Foundation(props) {
  return (
    <div className="border-dot ">
      Foundation Landing
      <p className="landinglinks">
        <NavLink to="FoundationSubA">
          Foundation Sub 1
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="FoundationSubB">
          Foundation Sub 2
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="FoundationSubC">
          Foundation Sub 3
        </NavLink>
      </p>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Foundation;
```

And lastly, implement the FoundationSubA component, so it can be rendered:

```
import React from "react";

export default function FoundationSubA(props) {
  return <div className="border-dot-sub">Foundation Sub 3</div>;
}
```

I think that's all I did to get it to work. The Outlet will render subroutes that match the current url

Comment: only 'FoundationSubAll' required for FoundationSubA, FoundationSubB, FoundationSubC. links, FoundationSubAll will be loaded with Sub 1, Sub 2, Sub3 tab type links. so once the FoundationSubAll  loaded Sub 1 for FoundationSubA link, Sub 2 for FoundationSubB link, Sub3 for FoundationSubC link. should be active.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to accomplish here. Could you clarify what you want to happen when you navigate between the three tabs? Seems like the tabs don't actually depend on routing at all